# How can I use counterCache() for tracking view counts with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, counter-cache

Every time a user views a submission, I track the count and tie it to a session:

SubmissionsController:

```
// Count view
if ($this->Session->check('viewed_submission_' . $submissionId) !== true) {
    $clientIp = ip2long($this->request->clientIp());
    $this->SubmissionsViews->countView($submissionId, $clientIp);
    $this->Session->write('viewed_submission_' . $submissionId, true);
}
```

I'm keeping track of them in a SubmissionsViews table.

SubmissionsViews Model:

```
class SubmissionsViews extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'SubmissionsViews';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Submission' => array(
            'className' => 'Submission'
        )   
    );

    public function countView($submissionId, $clientIp) {
        $this->set('submission_id', $submissionId);
        $this->set('user_ip', $clientIp);
        $this->save($this->data);
    }   
}
```

My SubmissionsView table `submissions_views` has the following fields:

- id
- submission_id
- user_ip
- created

I'm trying to set up counterCache to keep track of additions to that table, but not sure how to set it up. I'm currently adding the counterCache in my `$belongsTo` within my Submission model:

```
class Submission extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User'
        ),
        'SubmissionsViews' => array(
            'counterCache' => true
        )   
    );
```

But it's telling me it can't find `Submission.submissions_views_id`. In the documentation, all it said was that I needed to add a field to my `submissions` table called `submissions_views_count`, so I'm confused how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Model names should be singlular, so `SubmissionViews` should be `SubmissionView`.
2. Your association is incorrect. `Submission` hasMany `SubmissionView`, not belongsTo.
3. counterCache needs to be specified in the `SubmissionView` model inside the belongsTo config for `Submission`, not in the `Submission` model file. Please read the manual more carefully.

Comment: My mistake. I do appreciate it though. Guess I need to go back and re-read the naming conventions. Thank you.